# combining column of list in r

Tags: r, list, multiple-columns

I have data that the first column is a list column and the second column is the corresponding number. I would like to combine entities in the first column based on the number of the second column. here is the example; the first column is a list of courses and the second column is the corresponding semester:

```
df:

course  sem
math00     1
phys1      2
NA         3
eng00      4
c("math00","Geo00")   1
math02         2
NA         3
```

the result would be:

```
course                         semester
c("math00","math00","Geo00")        1
c("phys1","math02")                 2
NA                                  3
eng00                               4
```

How can I do it in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the 'semester' column as `list`, grouped by 'semester', `unlist` 'course' and then `summarise` as a `list`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   group_by(semester) %>%
   summarise(course = list(unique(unlist(course))))
```

---

Or use `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(df['course'], df['semester'], FUN = function(x) list(unique(unlist(x))))
#   semester        course
#1        1 math00, Geo00
#2        2 phys1, math02
#3        3            NA
#4        4         eng00
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(course = I(list('math00', 'phys1', NA, 'eng00', 
    c('math00', 'Geo00'), 'math02',NA)), semester = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3))
```

Comment: using aggregate gives me an error: `invalid type (list) for variable 'course'.` while `class(df$course) gives [1] "list"`. where is the problem?

Comment: @Cina Earlier I didn't test it.  The `formula` method of `aggregate` seems to have an issue with `list`

Comment: thank you @akrun. one quick question; I want to add more columns like `df %>%
   group_by(semester) %>%
   summarise(course = list(unique(unlist(course)))
   summarise(course2 = list(unique(unlist(course2))))`. how can I add the second command to the previous one? ( `course2 ` code does not work)

Comment: @Cina If I understand, you may use `summarise_at` and specify the columns as 'course', 'course2' in it. i.e. `df %>% group_by(semester) %>% summarise_at(vars(matches('course')), funs(list(unique(unlist(.)))))`